# На шахматной доске определите поля, в которые может попасть конь за n ходов из указанной позиции

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Задание: На шахматной доске определите поля, в которые может попасть конь за n ходов из указанной позиции.

У меня почему-то выходит неправильно, если я считаю сама на шахматной доске.
Мне нужно распечатать с х и у , а также как на доске это выглядит. Шаги все отражать, включая последний n шаг.

Подскажите, в чем ошибка, как надо описывать, себе пометила комментарии (может я неправильно пометила комментарии, подскажите).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

bool prov(int x, int y, int razm) //проверяем правильную позицию квадратов коня
{
    return ((x >= 0) && (y >= 0) && (x < razm) && (y < razm));
}

void func(int** doska, int kon_x, int kon_y, int razm, int step)
{
    // Условие выхода из рекурсии
    if (step == 0)
    {
        doska[kon_y][kon_x] = 1;
        return;// Не нужно возвращать значение функции, так как меняется только состояние доски, а доска одна
    }
    
    // Количество возможных ходов 8
    int new_x[8] = { -2, -2, -1, -1, 1, 1, 2, 2 };
    int new_y[8] = { -1, 1, -2, 2, -2, 2, -1, 1 };
    
    // А теперь их перебираем
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        int x = kon_x + new_x[i];
        int y = kon_y + new_y[i];
        
        // Если новая позиция корректная
        if (prov(x, y, razm))
        {
            //doska[y][x] = 1, то делаем рекурсивный вызов
            func(doska, x, y, razm, step - 1);
        }
        
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int n, kon_x, kon_y, step;
    
    cout << "Введите размер поля: " ;
    cin >> n;
    while (n <= 0)
    {
        cin.clear();
        while (cin.get() != '\n');
        cout << "Неверно. Введите размер поля снова: ";
    }
    
    int** doska = new int* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        doska[i] = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            doska[i][j] = 0;
    }
    
    cout << "Введите позицию лошади:" << endl;
    cout << "номер строки x = ";
    cin >> kon_x;
    cout << "номер столбца y = ";
    cin >> kon_y;
    while ((kon_x <= 0) || (kon_y <= 0))
    {
        cin.clear();
        while (cin.get() != '\n');
        cout << "Неверно. Введите положение лошади снова: ";
    }
    
    // Уменьшается на единицу каждый индекс, так как пользователь считает с 1, а я с 0
    kon_x--;
    kon_y--;
    cout << "Введите количество шагов: ";
    cin >> step;
    while (step <= 0)
    {
        cin.clear();
        while (cin.get() != '\n');
        cout << "Неверно. Введите количество шагов снова: ";
    }
    
    func(doska, kon_x, kon_y, n, step); // печать с х и у
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << " " << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (doska[i][j] == 1)
                cout << "x = " << j + 1 << " " << "y = " << i + 1 << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    func(doska, kon_x, kon_y, n, step); // печать как на шахматной доске
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << doska[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я вообще не изучал c++, но уже вижу одну проблему в вашем коде. Дело в том, что переменные нужно называть говорящими именами, но **на английском языке**. Если вы не очень хорошо знаете английский, то можно хотя бы воспользоваться онлайн-переводчиком(криво переводит, но что поделаешь).

Comment: @Kromster форматирование уже исправил `@DmitryK`

Comment: @Зонтик не цепляйтесь к деталям, название переменных вообще вкусовщина, а тут они хотя бы по смыслу верные )

Comment: @Kromster вкусовщина??? Мне так не кажется. Везде (во всех книгах, во всех статьях, на нашем сайте) написано, что переменные должны называться английскими словами и не как больше.

Comment: @Зонтик По стандарту переменные должны называться латинскими буквами. А какими словами - это вкусовщина! Поддержу Kromster!

Comment: @DmitryK  возможно, вы имеете в виду, что из-за таких названий не будет ошибок при компиляции... В прочем, я не изучал с++, поэтому не буду спорить.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример, который "выходит не правильно". Пока не понятно что вы считаете правильным.

Answer (score 1):

Да, вы неправильно поставили комментарии. Вот тут вы закомментировали нужную операцию.

```
// Если новая позиция корректная
if (prov(x, y, razm))
{
    //doska[y][x] = 1, то делаем рекурсивный вызов  --- ошибка!!!

    // должно быть так
    doska[y][x] = 1; // то делаем рекурсивный вызов
    func(doska, x, y, razm, step - 1);
}
```

Ещё вы в `main()` дважды вызываете `func()`. Это не приводит к неправильным результатам, просто программа работает 2 раза дольше.

```
    ....
    func(doska, kon_x, kon_y, n, step); // печать с х и у       --- !!!
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ....
    }
    
    func(doska, kon_x, kon_y, n, step); // печать как на шахматной доске --- !!!
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ....
    }
```

Неправильно написана проверка. Если числа отрицательные - получится вечный цикл.

```
    cin >> n;
    while (n <= 0)
    {
        cin.clear();
        while (cin.get() != '\n');
        cout << "Неверно. Введите размер поля снова: ";
    }
```

Такая же ошибка с проверкой первоначальных координат фигуры и количества шагов.
Наверное все же стоит ограничить размер доски. Ну по крайней мере количеством символов в строке - чтобы можно было напечатать вашу доску. Или просто сказать, что размер = 8.

Нет проверки, что введенное положение фигуры находится на доске - из-за этого будет выход за пределы массива - это UB и программа рухнет (если повезет).

Ну и по мелочам:
Шахматная фигура называется "конь"

```
cout << "Введите позицию лошади:" << endl;
cout << "Неверно. Введите положение лошади снова: ";
```

И в шахматах сначала говорят позицию строки а потом столбца, а у вас наоборот.

```
doska[kon_y][kon_x] = 1;
doska[y][x] = 1;
```

Comment: А как же классика, *«— Лошадью ходи, — век воли не видать!»* ))

Comment: @Kromster Так потому она и классика, что «— Лошадью ходи».  :)

Comment: Поэтому и смайлики ))

Comment: Убрав комментарий вы изменили задачу. Было "ровно *n* ходов". Стало "не более *n* ходов".

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy  Да. Но тут в вопросе двойственность. Если с комментарием, то на доске не отмечались промежуточные позиции коня, а только конечные. Если читать "определите поля, в которые может попасть конь за n ходов" то комментарий там нужен. А если "шаги все отражать, включая последний n шаг.", то комментарий надо убрать.